# Taskbar Date missing when it is too long

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, date-time

```
ddd, MMM d y -> Mon, May 28 18
```

[image]

> Only happens when there is two M

Due to larger width required for M,the taskbar shows empty date
Removing the comma will also not worked.My Screen Resolution is 1024 X 768
Also tried in 1366 x 768 resolution laptop

```
ddd, MM d y -> Mon, 05 28 18
```

[image]

To reproduce it,at cmd `date 05-28-18` because it has two M's (Mon and May)

Comment: Can you show us screenshots please?

Comment: Your resolution is quite low. Can you change your resolution higher? Does it have an effect on visibility of the date?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen Changed to  1280x1024 and some more.Again the same

Comment: @AulisRonkainen Could you able to reproduce it.

Comment: @SmartManoj: Sorry, I'm not able to reproduce this problem. If I change the format to "ddd, MMM d y", the date doesn't disappear. The month just changes to a longer form.

Comment: Well, my date is currently 29.05.18, because of my locale and I cannot change the date, because it is controlled by my organization. Could you specify why do you think that the actual date matters and what is so special about that date?

Comment: @AulisRonkainen No special about the date. This occurs when the string contains 2 W or 2 M so it gets too long .